# DebugDiag Analysis is taking too long to generate the report

Tags: iis, cpu-usage, debugdiag

I am using DebugDiag Analysis tool in the server to generate report for the dump file which is 1.74 GB and it's running for more than a day and could not generate report. I also tried running the tool in separate computer (local)

https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

It stops on "Preloading symbol files (this may take a while)"

Comment: That tool relies on internet connection back to Microsoft symbol server to download the necessary symbol files. If you don't have such a machine internally, the report generation can die in miserable way.

Comment: Thanks. I also figured it out. By un-ticking Symbol search paths to use for Analysis, I can generate the report.

Comment: a symbol-free report is usually of less help.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the tool (2.3 at the moment) from http://debugdiag.com

Comment: Mine is stuck in Dump x of 924, Reporting Input Summary... Any advice on speeding this up?